Chainlink how to account for potential charge in the future?
I plan to use the price feed for BTC/USD form chainlink aggregator (0xF4030086522a5bEEa4988F8cA5B36dbC97BeE88c)
https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses?network=ethereum&page=1&search=btc#overview
Now, currently I see no mention of any fee to use it but I do know that that oracles charge in LINK to provide the price.
Reading around I found out that apparently it is "free" for now because the fees are sponsored but that might not be true in the future.
I currently read the price like this:
priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
        0xF4030086522a5bEEa4988F8cA5B36dbC97BeE88c // BTC / USD - Ethereum Mainnet 
    );
(, int256 price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    require(price > 0, "Invalid price data");
    return uint256(price);

This makes me concerned that if I write my smart contract to use the price feed right now and in the future it requires payment it might break my contract.
What is the best way to go about this, is it possible to code my contract in a way that even if start charging for the aggregated data it will still work in the future?
